# Methods are called before Jquery is init

Tags: magento2, jquery

[image]

I have a lot of errors in my magento 2 site.
Seems that functions are called in a strange way. 
(They're in head, and they're supposed to be in the body)
How can i solve this?

Comment: it's default installation? change permission 777 for var, pub/static after deploy command.